# Deselect strip in the Video Sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor

By default, in order to deselect a strip in the *Video Sequencer*, but keep the others selected, you just need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> twice on the unwanted strip (same thing as with objects in the *3D View*). I've lost the shortcut and I'm trying to restore it, I guess it is supposed to be under *SequencerCommon > Sequencer > Sequencer (Global)* (I've tried *Select (Toggle)* but it doesn't seem to work).

**Edit:** Mmh OK actually it seems like it's rather a problem of double click speed, I need to find where is the click speed setting...

Answer (score 0):

I actually just needed to increase the *Double Click Speed* in the *Preferences > Input > Mouse*:

[image]